# CheckMK Alert Handler Logging Error - Alert Handlers are triggering but not running the script

Tags: check-mk

CMK version:
Checkmk Enterprise Edition 2.1.0p28

OS version:
Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Error message:
— Logging error —\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n File “/omd/sites/Site01/lib/python3/cmk/base/events.py”, line 112, in event_keepalive\n event_function(context)\n File “/omd/sites/Site01/lib/python3/cmk/base/cee/alert_handling.py”, line 205, in process_alert\n execute_alert_rules(raw_context)\n File “/omd/sites/Site01/lib/python3/cmk/base/cee/alert_handling.py”, line 216, in execute_alert_rules\n execute_alert_handler_rule(rule, context)\n File “/omd/sites/Site01/lib/python3/cmk/base/cee/alert_handling.py”, line 321, in execute_alert_handler_rule\n run_process_alert_handler(handler_name, handler_params, context)\n File “/omd/sites/Site01/lib/python3/cmk/base/cee/alert_handling.py”, line 383, in run_process_alert_handler\n handler_pid, handler_pipe = run_alert_handler_async(\n File “/omd/sites/Site01/lib/python3/cmk/base/cee/alert_handling.py”, line 442, in run_alert_handler_async\n os.execv(handler_path, command_line_arguments)\nFile

I changed the alert_handlers folder and my specific jenkins.sh script to 777 to rule out any permissions issues. I have no idea why this is occurring now.

[image]

It fails for any server and does not seem to be related to the script itself or the alert handler configuration. It does not appear to be related to a version change since the alert handler was succeeding on the new version.

Comment: I think your script itself is failing. Maybe you can run it manually and check, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

CheckMK is easily corrupted it seems. After working with their devs, we came to this resolution:

Delete the alert handler rule in the GUI for the jenkins.sh script on the central site RedactedServerName

Delete ~/local/share/check_mk/alert_handlers/jenkins.sh (cp a backup to a safe place first) on central site RedactedServerName

activate changes -> This will sync a clean state to the remote sites.

After activating the changes:

create new ~/local/share/check_mk/alert_handlers/jenkins.sh as site user on the central site RedactedServerName and copy the code of the backup jenkins.sh file in it

To perform this I had to run the following code:

```
sudo omd su RedactedServerName
cd /opt/omd/sites/RedactedServerName/local/share/check_mk/alert_handlers
touch jenkins.sh
nano jenkins.sh
chmod +x jenkins.sh
```

Create alert handler rule in the GUI of the central site

Activate changes